# Game Theory: Finding a table with two or more weakly dominant equilibriums?

Tags: game-theory

Textbook question:

> (True/False) It is impossible to get more than one weakly dominant strategy
>   equilibrium.

I came up with this table below, which I think it depicts one weakly dominant strategy. For player 2, picking B weakly dominates A, and, for player 1, picking A weakly dominates B. Thus, there is one weakly dominant equilibrium at $(4, -2)$. I can't seem to find a table with more than two.

However, I can see that the table has two Nash equilibriums at $(2,-2$) and $(4, -2)$.

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
& \text{Player $2$} \\
\text{Player $1$} &
\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
& A & B \\ \hline
 A & (2,-2) & (4,-2) \\ \hline
 B & (2,3) & (3,4) \\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

UPDATE:

I tried doing another table with another row with the same payoff as the first row, and I think it now represents two weakly dominant strategies. Can someone confirm this?
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
& \text{Player $2$} \\
\text{Player $1$} &
\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
& A & B \\ \hline
 A & (2,-2) & (4,-2) \\ \hline
 B & (2,3) & (3,4) \\ \hline
 C & (2,-2) & (4,-2) \\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

Player 1 has two weakly dominant strategies $A$ and $C$.

Player 2 has one weakly dominant strategies $B$.

Thus, two weakly dominant equilibriums at $(A, B)$ and $(C, B)$

Answer (score 1):

Good attempt, but by introducing strategy $C$, $A$ is no longer weakly dominant. In fact, this should suggest to you the following conjecture:

> Weakly dominant strategies are unique.

Show why this is the case and the answer to your stated question should follow immediately.

Comment: Hmm, how is it no longer weakly dominant. Could you be more specific in your answer?

Comment: $A$ does not weakly dominate $C$.